# Maven parallel testing runs every tag not filter

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

First, I tried the following commands.

`mvn clean test -Dtags="@Account and @OCR"`

`mvn test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@Account and @OCR"`

`mvn test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@Account,@OCR"`

Everytime all tags are running. But I want to run filter my tags and multiple. By the way i tried also configuration my surefire plugin so i added paralel methods and threadcount tags but didin't work.

So here is my pom file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>LifeboxAutomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>LifeboxAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <project.build.directory>C:\Users\OneDrive\Belgeler\GitHub\LifeboxBackendApi\src\test</project.build.directory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.17.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-junit5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                <version>19</version>
            </dependency>






    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>src/test/**/*.java</includes>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my TestRunner :

```
package cucumberOptions;



import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features",
        glue = {"Steps","SQL"}

)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

So what sould i do. I searched everywhere but icant find yet. Thank you for advice

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the setup you're showing. Can you try with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and see if that works.

Comment: Try using -Dgroups=something instead of -Dtags=something

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard cucumber started to support 'and' for tags,  only 'or'. So try please:

```
@Account or @OCR
```

OR, you may set in your Runner:

```
@CucumberOptions(
...
        tags = tag1, tag2
...

)
```